# Ширина окна браузера вместе с полосой прокрутки

Tags: jquery

Почему скрипт выдает не ту ширину браузера что нужно? Добавляю к классу body значение max-width соответствующее ширине окна браузера, но выдается ширина вместе с боковой полосой прокрутки. Если тоже самое проделываю относительно любого другого блока, то полоса не считается.

```
$('body').css('max-width', $(window).width());
```

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй почитать [эту статейку](http://slyweb.ru/jquery/27.php)

Comment: Пожалуйста, публикуйте ссылки в качестве дополнения к вашему ответу, а не вместо него. После изменения или удаления материалов по ссылке ваш ответ в нынешней редакции не будет иметь смысла.

Answer (score 0):

Надо бы уточнить какого именно браузера? а то их > 80 + версии. Или вы живете только Chromo - м ? Правильный ответ - разная

Answer (score 0):

Вообщем проблему решил тем, что в самом скрипте поставил опцию добавления класса к body

```
    $body.addClass('search-fullscreen');
```

ниже, чем

```
$body .css('max-width', $(window).width());
```

Добавление класса, а затем и стилей к нему в css необходимо для корректного отображения полноэкранного поиска на сайте. Переставил местами в скрипте эти плюшки и получилось все зер-гуд. У сайта пропадает скроллбар, пока открыт оверлей, а ширина у body ставится какая должна - без учета его ширины